# Android error, when having Edittext lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

This gives me error:
EditText messageEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_text);
Why can I not do like this on a eittext with lines?

This is how the Edittext looks like

```
     <EditText android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="3" 
        android:gravity="top"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText messageEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_text);
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
EditText messageEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message_text);
```

(You're using the wrong ID name?)